# MacOS Messages: How to compile the attachments for a Messages conversation with an individual contact? ~/Library/Messages/Attachments/

Tags: macos, ios, messages, contacts.app

I am trying to compile the complete media exchange with a single MacOS/iOS contact.

For reference, I have ensured that the media is all downloaded from iCloud directly within the Messages (i) window for this conversation. This is a chat that contains numerous attachments of images, photos, gifs, and short-length video clips. I am able to locate where the files are supposedly stored:  `~/Library/Messages/Attachments/`

It is here that I am lost. The `.../Attachments/` directory contains subfolders that are a strange hierarchy with no visible naming reference to the individual that this chat is with on both my MacOS and iOS synced conversations.

How am I able to view the complete set of attachments from this chat conversation once they have been downloaded to my desktop? There are hundreds of subfolders that are even more cryptic in their naming convention with no reference to the actual Messages chat in question.

Screenshot is from MacOS showing `~/Library/Messages/Attachments/(first folder inside)/(contents)`

[image: Screenshot of directory listing]